# Terminating AWS EC2 instance fails - the instance is still running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

it seems that I have a technical issue regarding terminating the EC2 instance.

When I terminate it, a new instance is being created with the same name.

I terminate an EC2 instance. After a refresh, another instance was running so I started to terminate it.
After one another refresh of the page, a new instance started to run.

Do you maybe have any tips regarding this?

Comment: Do you have any Auto Scaling groups running? Or Spot Fleets?

Answer (score 2):

This instance seems to be a part of the autoscaling group which is continuously trying to meet the minimum capacity requirements. Delete that Autoscaling group first and then stop the instance or update Min capacity in autoscaling group to 0 it will be automatically terminated.

Comment: Adjusting the `Minimum` won't stop it from being re-created because Auto Scaling uses the `DesiredCapacity` to determine the number of instances.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein desired capacity is automatically adjusted on autoscaling event let say you have min 10 and max 20, the desired capacity will automatically set to 10 at the very start. So on the next scale up event, it will automatically be adjusted to a new number depending upon the increment or decrement an instance number. In this case, if we set the minimum to 0 it will set the desired capacity to 0 so the autoscaling group is compliant with the scaling policy. :)

Comment: That is incorrect. Changing the Minimum to a lower value _will not_ change the Desired Capacity. Only **scaling policies** will change the Desired Capacity (or if you make the minimum _above_ the Desired Capacity or Maximum _below_ the Desired Capacity).